# Access-Control-Allow-Credentials vs Access-Control-Expose-Headers in customized authentication

Tags: google-chrome, http, cors, http-authentication

So I'm implementing a web application using customized authentication.

The implementation now looks like (parentheses below quotes HTTP headers):

```
Client: (Authorization: <Username>:<Password>)
Server: (Authentication-Info: nextnonce=<signed token>)
Client: (Authorization: Bearer <signed token>) client includes this for all following communication
```

This works perfectly with the mobile app client, before I ran into a huge mass of CORS configuration in the web client.

I noticed that Chrome refused to get Authentication-Info header unless I adds it to the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header. And the value of Access-Control-Allow-Credentials doesn't matter at all. While the [document](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#user-credentials) says that the Credentials includes "HTTP authentication".

So what's the point of Access-Control-Allow-Credentials here. Is my understanding of "HTTP authentication" wrong?
And is my implementation of this app look good so far?

BTW, I've read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24689738/624379). But it doesn't explain this clearly i think.

Comment: A response of `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` from the server `cross.example.com` is used to indicate that the *client* is allowed to *use* credentials for `cross.example.com` when *making the request*. It has no impact on the ability to read particular response headers, but it may impact the ability to read the response totally. When you omit `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, can you read the response at all?

Comment: @apsillers yes, i can read all "simple headers", the headers allowed by Access-Control-Expose-Headers and the response body. So what's the propose of telling client whether it's allowed to use those headers? The server can simply remove those headers from Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Comment: @spsillers BTW, http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#user-credentials says "The Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header indicates whether the response to request can be exposed when the omit credentials flag is unset." Which by my understanding, is quite the same with Access-Control-Expose-Headers.

Comment: The language that describes them is quite different (though maybe difficult to parse). `Allow-Credentials` determines "*whether the response... can be exposed*" for a credentialed request, while `Expose-Headers` indicates "*which [response] headers are safe to expose*". `Allow-Credentials` is a boolean that allows the client to read the response to a credential request at all (since by default responses to credentialed requests cannot be read by the client script). `Expose-Headers` is a list of which headers in the response can be read (assuming the response is allowed to be read at all).