# Angular 2 not send Cookies

Tags: symfony, angular, cookies

I am developing a project in which to frontend using the **angular 2** and on the backend using the **symfony** as api , my problem and that when i try to do a resquest for symfony must send the **PHPSESSID** and this is not happening as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

I have looked on the internet and appears much to use withCredentials:true but it is always to give this error.

[image]

Someone can help me?

The cookie from the **PHPSESSID** exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you passing headers in the option when making the request? See below sample -

```
var body; // request body
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':'true' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, body, options)
            .map(response => response);
```

I am not sure if this would work for you but I had similar problem with CORS. Find more information about Access-Control-Allow-Credential header in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687313/what-exactly-does-the-access-control-allow-credentials-header-do) thread.