# why is XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials necessary even for same site Ajax requests

Tags: cookies, cross-domain

I am trying to implement an authentication service deployed in a different HTTP server from the one serving my login page.

The following diagram depicts my setup:
[image]

On step #1 my browser makes an `HTTP GET` request to fetch the login page. This is provided as the HTTP response in #2. My browser renders the login page and when I click the login button I send an `HTTP POST` to a different server (on the same localhost). This is done in #3. The authentication server checks the login details and sends a response that sets the cookie in #4.

The ajax POST request in #3 is made using jQuery:

```
$.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth-server/some/path/',
       {username: 'foo', password: 'foo'},
       someCallback);
```

The authentication service's response (assuming authentication was successful) has the following header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Set-Cookie: session-id=v3876gc9jf22krlun57j6ellaq;Version=1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept, authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 21 Nov 2016 16:17:08 GMT
```

So the cookie (`session-id`) is present in the HTTP response in step #4.

Now if the user tries to login again I would like the authentication service to detect that. To test that scenario I press the login button again in order to repeat the post in #3. I would have expected the second request to contain the cookie. However the second time I press the login button, the request header in the post sent out in #3 does not contain the cookie.

What I have discovered is that for the post in #3 to contain the cookie, I have to do it like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth-server/some/path',
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'text',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            data: {
                username : 'foo',
                password : 'foo',
            },
            success: someCallback
        });
```

Why would that be necessary? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) states that this is only required for cross-site requests. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7189502/274677) also uses `xhrFields` but only in relation to a cross-domain scenario. I understand that my case is not cross-domain as both the page that serves the script is on localhost, and the page to where the ajax request is sent is on the same host. I also understand that cookie domains are [not port specific](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16328399/274677). Moreover, since my cookie did not explicitly specify a domain, then [the effective domain is that of the request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1063760/274677) meaning `127.0.0.1` which is identical the second time I send the `POST` request (#3). Finally, the HTTP reponse on #4 already includes `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` which means that the resource [can be accessed by any domain in a cross-site manner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

So why did I have to use the `xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}` to make this work?

What I understand is that setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is simply enabling cross-site requests but that in order for cookies to be sent then the `xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}` should be used regardless (as explained in [MDN section on requests with credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)). Moreover, I understand that the request is indeed cross-site since the port number is important when deciding whether a request is cross-site or not. Whether the domain of a cookie includes ports is irrelevant. Is this understanding correct?

### update

I think this is explained very clearly in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24689738/274677), so maybe this question should be deleted.

Comment: yes, but they use different ports... this is already considered CORS

Comment: So are localhost:3000 & localhost:4000 same-site or cross-site ?
I understand they are cross-origin but what about site ?
In MDN docs for withCredentials, it talks about same-site not origin

Answer (score 4):

All parts of the origin must match the host(ajax target) for it to be considered same-origin. The 3 part of the origin `https://sales.company.com:9443` for example includes:

1. protocol/scheme (*https* - won't match http)
2. hostname (*`sales.company.com`* - won't match `subdomain.sales.company.com`)
3. port (*9443* - won't match 443)

[image]

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: So are localhost:3000 & localhost:4000 same-site or cross-site ?
I understand they are cross-origin but what about site ?
In MDN docs for withCredentials, it talks about same-site not origin