# Set the session of subdomain using ajax

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, subdomain

I'm using a domain like *www.example.com* and a sub-domain like *sub.example.com*.

I'm trying to call the `Login` function of sub.example.com.
In the end I cant set the session of sub.example.com for future functions to be called.

I'm using CodeIgniter in my sub-domain and my root domain just has an HTML page with native JavaScript. I wanted to use *sub.example.com* as my endpoint for all my sub-websites.

I tried changing the config of my subdomain(CI) to

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = ".example.com";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

and also the index.php file of my www.example.com to:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by setting `header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");`[SERVER-SIDE] and `$http.defaults.withCredentials = true;`[CLIENT-SIDE] using Angular `$httpProvider` upon request

And also don't forget to set the `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.example.com");`[SERVER-SIDE] my root domain to have an access to my sub-domain.

but if you have multiple domains/sub-domains to allow you can use below code

```
$http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];

if ($http_origin == "http://www.domain1.com" || $http_origin == "http://www.domain2.com" || $http_origin == "http://www.domain3.info")
{  
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");
}
```

for more info [Access-control-allow-credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687313/what-exactly-does-the-access-control-allow-credentials-header-do)

Answer (score 0):

In `codeigniter` you not need to `session_start();`.Just load `session` library and then try .

Load session library as:

```
$this->load->library('session');//from models,controllers and view..
```

But if you are outside from models,views and controller..Load CI `session` library as follows:

1.First create instance of CI

```
$this->CI =& get_instance();
```

2.Then Load Library

```
$this->CI->load->library('session');
```

For more see here https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#destroying-a-session

Comment: yes i understand this situation, what i wanted to happen is to set the session of my subdomain using the root domain. but after login function.. and try other function to my subdomain i'm not logged in anymore.

Comment: It is not  a good way to use session of one domain to another?In case of root domain and subdomain check first...whether this domains are sharing same CI system files or not?

Comment: why it is not a good way? then what would be the possible solution for my situation? all i want is to set the session of subdomain using root domain via ajax. so that for every call to the functions of subdomain its already logged in and have access to functions.

Comment: If both domains contains different CI system files..Then not possible to use session of one domain to another.

Comment: So you have to run multiple applications sharing same CI system files..

Comment: for more see here...https://philsturgeon.uk/codeigniter/2009/07/08/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter/

Comment: Hello i already solved my problem.. please see my own answer. if you have something to suggest you may do so. thank you Mr @Hikmat Sijapati