# ASP .NET Core use multiple CORS policies

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-core, cors

I am trying to setup 2 CORS policies.  One as an api default and the other to use on `Controllers` as I need them.  The reason I want to do this is because I have an endpoint that takes in an object with email info and sends an email (to use with the contact me box on my webpage) and have it only accept requests from my domain.

My `startup.cs` file snippet:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Example",
                    builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://www.example.com"));
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
            });

            services.AddMvc();
            //other configure stuff
        }


 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseCors(builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            builder.AllowAnyMethod();
            builder.WithOrigins("AllowAll");
        });

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

My `emailcontroller.cs` file:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyAPI.Models;
using MyAPI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyAPI.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/Email")]
    [EnableCors("Example")]
    public class EmailController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public EmailController(IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task Post([FromBody] Email email)
        {
            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(email);
        }
    }

}
```

Javascript used to send email:

```
function sendEmail(email)
{
    var urlToApi = "http://<ipToApi>:5000/api";
    $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(email),     
            url: urlToApi + "/email/",
            success: function(data) {  
                console.log(data);
                console.log('probably sent');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log(textStatus);
                alert("There was like, an error doing that");
            }
        });
}
```

This is what I get trying to send from http://www.example.com

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://<ipToApi>:5000/api/email/. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
 resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**EDIT**

This works:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Example",
                    builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://www.example.com")
                                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                                        .AllowAnyMethod());
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                                        .AllowAnyMethod());
            });
```

Comment: You're setting your origin as "AllowAll"

Comment: @Mardoxx I thought that would just set the default.  If I comment all that out can I just use the [EnableCors("mypolicy")] on all my controllers?

Comment: You should be using `app.UseCors("AllowAll");`

Comment: You are also not allowing any methods/headers. CORS spec says you don't set any headers if any checks fails to pass (at least that is how ASPNET Core interprets it!) So that is why I believe you get the generic `...-Allow-Origin not present` error. If you add in `AllowAnyHeader` and `AllowAnyMethod` to both policies it may work as expected.

Comment: @Mardoxx thanks! if you post that as an answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To set a default CORS policy use `app.UseCors(string policyName)` overload.

Your CORS requests will be failing because you are rejecting all headers and methods. From what I read, the CORS specification states that you shouldn't set any headers at all if any of the checks fail. See implementation [here](https://github.com/aspnet/CORS/blob/1e148819af302dd38d9a7e5baaeecc8ca514cd6d/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors/Infrastructure/CorsService.cs#L97), this is most likely why your client will be receiving the standard `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present` error, as *no* headers are added at all, even though the `Origin` check passes.

The following should work as expected, and your `[EnableCors(...)]` decorator should override the default!

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Example",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://www.example.com")
                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                .AllowAnyMethod());
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                .AllowAnyMethod());
    });

    services.AddMvc();
    //other configure stuff
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseCors("AllowAll"); //Default

    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

You may need to add `.AllowCredentials()` to your policies, but I am not sure. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687313/what-exactly-does-the-access-control-allow-credentials-header-do) perhaps?

Comment: I don't think the controller level [EnableCors] overrides the default.  This only appears to work because the default is to allow all.

Comment: Using `app.UseCors("AllowAll");` uses the middleware which fires before the mvc cors attrbutes , and is not overridden by them . This answer I think is a little misleading as yes it only works as 2 cors policys are applied one after another, this helped me in the end - https://andrewlock.net/a-deep-dive-in-to-the-asp-net-core-cors-library/

Answer (score 9):

Configure Method

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("Policy1");
app.UseCors("Policy2");
app.UseAuthentication();
```

ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Policy1",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://mywebsite.com")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod());
        options.AddPolicy("Policy2",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4300", "http://yourwebsite.com")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod());
    });
```

Comment: OP is asking how to configure 2 policies.

Comment: Where do you define the policy "CorsApi"?

Comment: updated above for both comments thanks