# How to enable Cors for every type of request in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

How to enable Cors for every type of request in asp.net core 3.1?

I am following the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1) but they seem to not work.

Note: I am able to achieve cors for specific domains but not to every domain. For example the below configuration I have applied to my project:

1. In the `ConfigureServices();` method I added:

   services.AddCors();
2. In the `Configure()` method I added:

   app.UseCors(builder =>
   {
       builder
       .WithOrigins()
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .AllowAnyHeader()
       .AllowCredentials();
   });

But when I try to access the API with jQuery from another url then I get:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44314/Reservation' from origin 'https://localhost:44361' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Now If i put the URL in the WithOrigins() method I am able to access the API:

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder
    .WithOrigins("https://localhost:44361")
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials();
});
```

My question is how to give access to the API to every URL(i.e domain, subdomain,etc) without restriction. Applying * does not work.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to allow any origin which you do with the following:

`builder.AllowAnyOrigin()`

**Any Origin with AllowCredentials**

not allowing credentials to be sent from any origin is by design.

You *can* get around this by using the following

`builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)`

I dont think it is a great solution because it removes the benefit of useCredentials().

**Note**

`useCredentials` is not required for sending a JWT in the header. It is for if you need to send cookies in the request. Allowing any origin and enabling `useCredentials` can lead to security vunerabilities which is why it is not allowed by default.

**For more information you should read**

[What exactly does the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687313/what-exactly-does-the-access-control-allow-credentials-header-do)

and

[CORS: Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19743396/5517088)

Comment: I tried this but i get error in this ": 'The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and credentials at the same time. Configure the CORS policy by listing individual origins if credentials needs to be supported.'"

Comment: This is part of the design of CORS. When you are sending credentials you need to specify the origins you will allow these credentials to be sent from

Comment: thank you. I also had to remove the .AllowCredentials(); for it to work after adding builder.AllowAnyOrigin() like you said.

Comment: After removing .AllowCredentials(); i am still able to send JWT token in the header so I don't think credentials sending is prevented in this case.

Comment: AllowCredentials(); is for cookies as far as know. I updated my question to provide some more info and links to two useful questions

Answer (score 3):

This should be good for you. Just ignore the MVC part I just add in for you to make sure your pipeline order is correct

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      services.AddCors();
      services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseCors(
        options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
    );

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done this way and it works.

```
public class Startup
{
    private const string CORS_POLICY = "CORSPolicy";
    ...

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: CORS_POLICY,
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  builder
                                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                                  .AllowAnyMethod()                                      
                                  .SetIsOriginAllowed(options => true)
                                  .AllowCredentials();
                              });
        });
        
        services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest);
        ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
     ...
        app.UseCors(CORS_POLICY);
        app.UseMvc();
     ...
    }
```