# ReactJS/ASP.Net Core 2.1 Version CORS Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core, cors

When I do axios post by React JS, I get the following CORS error to ASP.Net Core side.

> Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed
> by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
> https://localhost:5001/api/vendorregistration

I installed the following as my Nuget Packages and did not apply any other form below but it didn't work.

- Microsoft.AspNet.Cors. 5.2.7 Version
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors 2.1.1 Version

[How to enable Cors for every type of request in asp.net core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60636051/how-to-enable-cors-for-every-type-of-request-in-asp-net-core-3-1)

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("ReactPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyOrigin();
               //    .AllowCredentials();
        }));

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseCors("ReactPolicy");
        app.UseMvc();

    }
}
```

**VendorRegistrationController.cs**

```
namespace Bait.Controllers
{

[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[EnableCors("ReactPolicy")]
```

ReactJS Side **RegistrationForm.tsx**

```
 const handleFormSubmit = async (values: any): Promise<any> => {
   const response = await axios.post<User>('https://localhost:5001/api/vendorregistration', { data: values })
   console.log(response);
 };
```

Comment: Your configuration for cors policy is correct and I also copied your code to my newly created asp.net core2.1 project and it really worked, so I'm afraid you need to rebuild or just reopen your visual studio and then restart your application and try again, it's more likely not take effect in my opinion.

Comment: @TinyWang I uninstalled the project and re-installed it and added the same files. However, when I trigger the project on the ReactJS side, I still get the same error. I wonder if it's HomeController.cs or something else I forgot?

Comment: Many thanks sir and happy coding : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you pls check my code snippet as it worked for me. I copied your startup file so I just put the using packages here.

My test controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebAppMVCcore2.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors("ReactPolicy")]
    public class HelloController : Controller
    {
    
        [HttpPost]
        public string Index()
        {
            return "hello";
        }
    }
}
```

And my startup file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace WebAppMVC_core2
{}
```

And my test react code:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      const response = axios.post('https://localhost:44326/api/hello').then(res=>{
        console.log('res=>',res);            
      })
      console.log(response);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: I updated my controller file. This worked for me. Thanks

Comment: @Yavuz I'm glad to hear you solved your issue, you updated your controller method sir? That sounds amazing. Anyway it's great. Thanks for your reply sir and could you pls accept my post as the answer? I really appreciate you for it.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to use in every actions in the controller. just put   app.UseCors("ReactPolicy"); line before `app.UseStaticFiles(); line`

```
app.UseCors("ReactPolicy");
```

Hope it'll work!

Comment: app.UseStaticFiles(); first app.UseCors("ReactPolicy"); I added.
However, it didn't work.