# Blocked by CORS policy despite having policy added to allow any and middleware set

Tags: asp.net, angular, cors

I have been stuck on this issue for days. I'm attempting to add a CORS policy so my application does not require a CORS plugin (extension) to run. I've went through multiple tutorials of how to correctly implement the add policy and how to order the middleware. My application backend should send map data to the front end but without the plugin I receive the infamous
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5001/maps/NaturalEarthII/tilemapresource.xml' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error. From my understanding everything is setup as it should be but the results are not agreeing, Please help! There is no controllers

ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Enable Gzip Response Compression for SRTM terrain data
        services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
        {
            options.EnableForHttps = true;
            options.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
                new[] { "application/vnd.quantized-mesh" });
            options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
        });
        // Add CORS Service so Tile Server works
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            //Here ive attepted implementing default and specific policy
            //I've also tried only allowing specific origins and allowing any method + header
            //no luck. I will change this to be more specific once i get maps to show

            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                ); 
            options.AddPolicy("allowAny",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5001")
                .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                .AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
                );
        });
        services.AddControllers();
        //services.AddSpaStaticFiles(config => config.RootPath = "wwwroot");
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(MessageBus), new MessageBus());
    }
```

Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
        {
            
            applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            // Use Gzip Response Compression for SRTM terrain data
            app.UseResponseCompression();

            // We must set the Content-Type and Content-Encoding for SRTM terrain files,
            // so the Client's Web Browser can display them.
            app.Map("/terrain/srtm", fileApp =>
            {
                fileApp.Run(context =>
                {
                    if (context.Request.Path.Value.EndsWith(".terrain")) {
                        context.Response.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/vnd.quantized-   mesh";
                        context.Response.Headers["Content-Encoding"] = "gzip";
                    }
                    return context.Response.SendFileAsync(
                        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ("data/terrain/srtm/" + context.Request.Path.Value)));
                });
            });
            Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "data"));
            // Make the data/maps directory available to clients
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "data")),
            });
            
            app.UseRouting();
            //Add the default policy thats create in the conf services method
            app.UseCors();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseWebSockets();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors("allowAny"));
            bus = (MessageBus)app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(MessageBus));
...
```

In the Add cors Ive attempted implementing default and specific policy
I've also tried only allowing specific origins and allowing any method + header. No luck. I will change this to be more specific once i get maps to show

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    ); 
                options.AddPolicy("allowAny",
                    builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5001")
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                    .AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
                    );
            });
```

Comment: Allowing any origin is insecure (as is allowing any method or header) so I'd remove those. It appears as though you want to allow the origin `http://localhost:5001`, as that is what your error says... If you add a named policy, you have to use that policy in the Configure step (like [the documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware))

Comment: If you really want to allow anything through, see [How to enable Cors for every type of request in asp.net core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60636051/215552)

Comment: When I tried previous things I had it set as 5001. I just messed up and put localhost:4200 on the origin . its corrected now but gives the same error. I also have been doing everything that the documentation and 'enable CORS for all' link tells me to do. I'm missing a piece. As far as the allow all, Ill refine it after I get the map images @Heretic_Monkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying endless attempts at making the back end work I gave up and implemented a reverse proxy on the front end. I can now use my web application without a CORS plugin.
proxy.conf.json:

```
{
    "/maps":{
        "target": "http://localhost:5001",
        "secure": false
    } 
}
```

angular.json:

```
...
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-    angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "cesium-angular:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your allowed origin to be the service itself rather than address of your UI.

In your case your origin should be `http://localhost:4200` not `5001`

Add this to your `program.cs`

```
var app = builder.Build();
...
app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowCredentials()
                            .WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200"));
```

Do note that the `UseCors()` needs to be called before `UseAuthentication()` and `UseAuthorization()`

I also can't see where you are calling your `ConfigureServices` method

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I tried this before posting. You can see above I also tried allowing any origin.

Comment: @GavinAnderson are sure you are calling your `ConfigureServices()` method as I cannot see where you do that in the code provided, also have you tried specifying the policy in the `UseCors()` rather than outsource it somewhere else?

Comment: Yessir, I called the useCors() in both the format of no parameters and also the app.UseCors(policyNameHere) as far as the call to configure services it’s never directly called which is intentional but instead called through useStartup which invokes configureServices then configure.

Comment: @GavinAnderson you might also need to try making `ConfigureServices()` an extension method or passing the instance of `IServiceCollection` by reference