# Azure Functions Core Tool - Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider'

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

When I try to run Azure function in the local environment, I get this error:

[image]

I get the same error if I try to use v2.

I already checked all those issues:

Azure/azure-functions-host#4521
Azure/azure-functions-host#4520

Also, I have tried to reinstall Visual Studio and update to the latest version of Azure Function Core Tools.

This issue appears if I run a function app via Visual Studio 2019 or from the command line using func host start. I have tried to set a different port numbers as well.

Does someone have a solution to this issue?

**UPDATE**

I figured out VS starts x64 version and it can cause the problem. When I download func-cli-3.0.2358-x86.msi, set up debug for the project, it works.

How can I set VS to run x86 cli?

Comment: which version of "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" is referenced in your project?

Comment: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.5

Answer (score 5):

If your `local.settings.json` is along the lines of:

```json
{
  ...
  "Host": {
    "CORS": "*",
    "CORSCredentials": true
  }
}
```

Try replacing `*` with a specific domain e.g. `http://localhost:8000` or something.

Answer (score 3):

There may be error with your local.settings.json.

For example, the error:
[image]

can be fixed by removing:

```
 "Host": {
"CORS": "*",
"CORSCredentials": true
}
```

from  local.settings.json

Comment: Works, why? Since this is the recommended by Microsoft?

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Elliott de Launay's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1879252/elliott-de-launay).   The cause may be because the settings
"CORS": "*", and "CORSCredentials": true, are not compatible.

You either need to specify the domains with "CORSCredentials": true, or set "CORSCredentials":  false.

For example:

```
"Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*",
    "CORSCredentials": false
}
```

Versus

```
"Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "https://127.0.0.1:XXXX,https://localhost:XXXX,
    "CORSCredentials": true
}
```

This SO answer by @monsur (https://stackoverflow.com/users/107250/monsur) gives a good explanation of the implications of setting CORSCredentials: true or false.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24689738/12995968

References:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-local#local-settings-file

Comment: This works as said here

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an instance of x64 running and is blocking it from running again with that error message. Will probably be the same with x86 if you run several instances of that.