# What does supports_credential mean in the Laravel cors.php file?

Tags: laravel

In the config/cors.php file I have the key value pair

`'supports_credentials' => false,`

What does "supports_credentials" do for true and what for false?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24689738/7796116

Answer (score 7):

If your Request includes an Authorization header or uses Credentials mode, set the supports_credentials value in the config to true. This will set the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Header to true.

for example, if you need to send cookies from the front-end to the back-end you need to set 'supports_credentials' to true.
read more in the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials).

Comment: Answer shared too late!.

Comment: Hello @SandeshKhutalSaheb
I am sorry that you found my answer late, but I'm afraid to tell you I had the same question in mind. I was looking for an answer, and I couldn't find yours here. So I went and looked for a convenient answer and brought it.
I never heard someone say it's a late answer because it would be helpful to others, If it was the case, then Stack Overflow wouldn't allow **late answers** in here.
I would love to see a useful comment from you next time.
have a nice day.